# If I is an irreducible ideal, and P is a prime ideal, is (I+P)/P irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit, and $P$ a prime ideal.

My question is:

> If $I$ is an irreducible ideal in $A$, is $(I+P)/P$ irreducible in $A/P$? If not, can you show a counterexample?

Of course, if $(I+P)/P$ is reducible in $A/P$, then $I+P$ is reducible in $A$, because 
$$ \dfrac{I+P}{P} = \dfrac{J_1}{P} + \dfrac{J_2}{P} \Rightarrow
I+P = J_1 + J_2 $$
but i don't think this is enough to conclude that $I$ is reducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

$I=(xy-z)$ is irreducible (it is even prime) in $K[x,y,z]$, but $(I+(z))/(z)=(xy)$ is not irreducible in $K[x,y,z]/(z)=K[x,y]$.